# Casting to a specified generic function parameter

Tags: swift, generics, casting

Let's say I have a `Commander` object that executes commands. The return type is not always the same and changes according to the command.

I'd like to be able to use a function that forwards a command to the Commander, tests if the result is of a certain type (passed as a parameter), before calling a success closure if the cast succeeded, and a failure closure otherwise.

I've tried using generic parameters with something like this:

```
func postCommand<T>(command: String, expectedResponseType: T, success: T -> Void, failure: (NSError?) -> Void) {
    Commander.execute(command, completion: { (response: AnyObject?) in
        guard let content = response as? T else {
            failure(nil)
            return
        }
        success(content)
    })
}
```

Calling it that way

```
self.postCommand("command", expectedResponseType: [String: AnyObject], success: { (content: [String: AnyObject]) in
    print("Success")
}) { (error: NSError?) in
    print("Failure")
}
```

But I get an error from the compiler:

```
Cannot convert value of type '([String : AnyObject]) -> Void' to expected argument type '_ -> Void'
```

If I try to do the cast like this:

```
guard let content = response as? expectedResponseType
```

the compiler complains that `expectedResponseType` is not a type.

I can't figure out how to do that. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the casting, but with the type of the `expectedResponseType:` parameter.

If you wish to pass a type to a function, you need to use [the metatype type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455) as the argument type. In this case, the `expectedResponseType:` parameter of your function should be of type `T.Type` – allowing you to pass in a type to define `T`.

```
func postCommand<T>(_ command: String, expectedResponseType: T.Type, success: (T) -> Void, failure: (NSError?) -> Void) {
    // ...
}
```

You'll also need to use the postfix `.self` in order to refer to the actual type of whatever you pass into the `expectedResponseType:` parameter:

```
self.postCommand("command", expectedResponseType: [String: AnyObject].self, success: { content in
    print("Success")
}) { error in
    print("Failure")
}
```

Although you should note that the type of `T` can be inferred directly from the success closure you pass to the function:

```
func postCommand<T>(_ command: String, success: (T) -> Void, failure: (NSError?) -> Void) {
    // ...
}
```

```
self.postCommand("command", success: { (content: [String: AnyObject]) in
    print("Success")
}) { error in
    print("Failure")
}
```